# Updated Android Studio 0.8.14, emulators not running fast (not using HAXM)

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I updated to Android studio (beta) 0.8.14, there's a lot of change in AVD manager. The problem is none of my emulator is now running on fast virtual mode (using HAXM), which used to run before the update. I have 64bit windows with Intel VT enabled and x86 intel atom images for devices.Even the normal running mode is too slow compared to before.I dont know if this is a bug or something since its beta.

Comment: I dont know who down-voted that WITHOUT any reason...people just...

Comment: There was a version upgrade to HAXM try updating via the Android SDK Tools then after it upgrades remember to rerun the installer

Comment: thnx , I did it before u said, the problem is not there, it runs in fast mode but doesnt show any notification like before, so u need to run it frm terinal. YET ,it runs much slower than bfore in fast virtual mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the AVD's thru command shell n now it shows the details, and it shows it is running under fast virtual mode but still very slow compared to before.